# Select on one row table takes seconds

Tags: performance, oracle, hibernate

I am experiencing very low performance in my web application in which trivial HTTP requests take dozens of seconds to be processed. Tracing down the application code I discovered the majority of time is spent executing the first DB query, even if it is as simple as a `SELECT` on a single row-single column table. This happens for every HTTP request, independently from the query performed. After this first pathological DB interaction the remaining queries go smoothly.

I am using Hibernate on top of an Oracle DB (using jdbc).

It is not a problem of connection pool since I am successfully using `Hibernate-c3p0`,  neither it seems to be related to Oracle itself, because all query returns immediately if performed directly on DB.

Furthermore, Hibernate `SessionFactory` is correctly created only once, at application start up time and concurrency is not a problem at all since tests have been done with single user.

Finally, my DB IP address is correctly resolved in my application server `/etc/hosts` so that even DNS related issues can be discarded (I am using two distinct virtual machines, DB and APP server).

I do not know what to look for, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your session factory object is being spun up on the first query.  Generally I try to initialize the session factory on application startup to avoid this when issuing the first query because generally the user can see this slowdown.  When doing it up front in application startup you will avoid this.

Comment: Thank you very much, even if at first I was sceptical reading your answer, you got it right. The problem is I was tracing down some performance issue and everytime I made some change I recompiled my source. In this way `SessionFactory` was called and my time statistics were inflated. If I had just repeated the test one more time without recompiling I would have resolved.
Thanks for your time.

(Thank you Serrano too for help me formatting)